# How do I avoid the error "unsupported operand types" in the following code? (Python 3)

Tags: python

```
#program places commas in a number when needed
num = eval(input("Enter a number between 1000 and 999999: "))
inter = num // 1000
print(inter + ",000")
```

The console gives me the error of "unsupported operand types for +: "int and "str"" and I'm very confused. I'm a beginner to the program.

Comment: Don't ever `eval` user input. If you expect a number, do `int(input(...))`.

Comment: FYI, the issue is in your `print` statement; `inter` is a number, but you're trying to add it to the string `',000'`. Either use a formatted string or use `str()` to convert `inter` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print(inter + ",000")` with `print(str(inter) + ",000")`.